# Como selecionar apenas um botão de rádio?

Tags: java, swing

No swing do Java, um usuário pode selecionar mais de um botão de rádio simultaneamente, para isso não acontecer, pode-se fazer:

```
private void radio1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (radio1.isSeleced()) {
        radio2.isSelected(false);
    }
}
```

Mas isso é muito não prático, imagine uma situação que exija dezenas de botões de rádio, seria trabalhoso demais.

---

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer o que desejo? Pensei em usar um *foreach* colocando todos os botões de rádio dentro de um vetor, mas não consegui abstrair nada.

Comment: Não está esquecendo de agrupar os `JRadioButton` em um `ButtonGroup` não? O comportamento padrão de um RadioButton em um Group é manter apenas um selecionado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solução para isto é a utilização do `javax.swing.ButtonGroup` que permite agrupar em grupos os componentes `javax.swing.JRadioButton`.

**Exemplo:**

```
...
buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton3);
...
```

---

Ele pode ser utilizado com qualquer outro componente que herda a classe `AbstractButton` conforme a documentação [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html).